# Why is $f$ measurable iff $f^{-1}\{(-\infty , c) \}$ for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have just started a course in real analysis and I encountered this: Theorem 2.1.1 from Friedmans Modern Analysis, it is fairly straight forward modulo two technical details 1. and 2. below:

It begins with the following definition: Let $X_o$ be a measurable set in some fixed measurespace $(X,\mu,\sigma)$, then a function $f:X_o \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable if the preimage of any open set is measurable.

The theorem states that for such a function; $f$ is measurable iff for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ the preimage $f^{-1}\{(-\infty,c)\}$ and the sets $f^{-1}(\pm \infty)$ are measurable.

Proof: $\Rightarrow$ is immediate from the definition. In the book, the proof of the converse is as follows: Assume $f$ satisfies the above confitions then:

1. $f^{-1}\{(-\infty,c]\} = \cap_nf^{-1}\{(-\infty, c +
       \frac{1}{n})\}$, the RHS is measurable as the intersection of measurable sets of the $\sigma$-algebra, hence
2. $f^{-1}\{(a,b)\} = f^{-1}\{(-\infty,b)\} - f^{-1}\{(-\infty,a]\} $.

I understand that as an interval on the real line $(-\infty,c] = \cap_n (-\infty,c+\frac{1}{n})$, moreover I understand that as a set on the real line $(a,b) = (-\infty, b) - (-\infty, a]$ but how do I know from the definition of a measurable function that the two measurable sets in 1. and 2. are equal in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Perhaps it is just trivial and I can't see it, any insight to what I fail to understand would be helpful!

Comment: I am not sure if this answers your question, but $ \sigma ( \{ (-\infty,c) \}_c )$ is the Borel $\sigma$-field.

Comment: I am not familiar with the term Borel $\sigma$-field, how is it defined?

Comment: The $\sigma$ algebra generated by the open sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct name of the book you quote in your post is *[Foundations of Modern Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486640620)*. The author is Friedman. (There is no "s" is the author's name.) The theorem you quote is not complete. Here is the one in the book:

> **Theorem 2.1.1** Let $f$ be a extended real-valued function defined on a measurable set $X_0\subset X$, $X$ a measure space. $f$ is measurable if and only if
>
> - (i) for every real number $c$, the set $f^{-1}((-\infty, c))$ is measurable.
> - (ii) the sets $f^{-1}(-\infty)$ and $f^{-1}(\infty)$ are measurable.

A key property of the <s>inverse</s> map $f^{-1}$ you need to know in order to understand the proof is that it *commutes* with unions, intersections and complements:
$$
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(\cup_{\alpha\in A} E_\alpha)&=\cup_{\alpha\in A} f^{-1}(E_{\alpha}),\tag{1}\\
f^{-1}(\cap_{\alpha\in A} E_{\alpha})&=\cap_{\alpha\in A} f^{-1}(E_\alpha),\tag{2}\\
f^{-1}(E^c)&=\big(f^{-1}(E)\big)^c.\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Note that this true for *any* function $f$. It has nothing to do with its measurability.

This property tells you why you have the two identities in your `1` and `2`. For instance, (2) tells you that
$$
f^{-1}((\infty,c])=f^{-1}(\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n)
=
\cap_{n=1}^\infty f^{-1}(A_n)
$$
where $A_n=(-\infty,c+\frac1n)$.

Comment: Thank you for making the proof and reference clear. I did not know that the preimage (i assume you meant preimage and not inverse function?) commutes with unions, intersections and complements, then it is clear, thank you!

Comment: I agree that calling it "inverse" may be confusing. Yes, $f^{-1}(U)$ means "the preimage of $U$ under the mapping $f$".

Answer (score 1):

The collection of all open rays generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (i.e. the canonical $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R$). [By some theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mapping_Measurable_iff_Measurable_on_Generator), it suffices to check measurability of a function on the generating set — in this case the collection of all open rays. Hence, once $f^{-1}\{(-\infty, c)\}\in\sigma$ for arbitrary $c\in\mathbb R$, $f$ is measurable. The theorem is, unsurprisingly, also (implicitly) used in the "$\Leftarrow$" direction: Since $f^{-1}\{(-\infty,c)\}\in\sigma$ for arbitrary $c\in\mathbb R$ it can be shown that this implies $f^{-1}\{(a,b)\}\in\sigma$. But the collection of open intervals also generates the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, hence we have proved measurability on a generator which implies measurability of the function.